# Jest-Vue-Quasar unit testing issue with ES modules

Tags: unit-testing, jestjs, quasar

I'm have issues testing with Jest, I don't have much experience.  My component is using my own ES **Node Module**, an it works fine in runtime, except when running the test., I'm using Vue3, Quasar and Jest.

I Tried different things such as mapping (moduleNameMapper) in the jest config file without success.

I get this error while running the test.

`Cannot find module 'my-module' from 'src/Helpers.js'`

In Helpers.js this is how is declared

```
import EventEmitter from 'events';
import { v4 as uuid } from 'uuid';
import { testMethod  } from 'my-module';
```

This is my jest.config.js

```
const esModules = ['quasar/lang', 'lodash-es'].join('|');

/* eslint-env node */
module.exports = {
  globals: {
    __DEV__: true,
    // TODO: Remove if resolved natively
    // See https://github.com/vuejs/vue-jest/issues/175
    'vue-jest': {
      pug: { doctype: 'html' },
    },
  },
  // noStackTrace: true,
  // bail: true,
  // cache: false,
  verbose: true,
  // watch: true,
  collectCoverage: true,
  reporters: [
    'default',
    [ 'jest-junit', {
      outputDirectory: '<rootDir>/',
      outputName: 'junit.xml',
    } ]
  ],
  coverageReporters: [
    "json", "lcov", "text", "clover", "cobertura"
  ],
  coverageDirectory: '<rootDir>/coverage',
  collectCoverageFrom: [
    '<rootDir>/src/**/*.vue',
    //'<rootDir>/src/**/*.js',
    '<rootDir>/src/**/*.ts',
    //'<rootDir>/src/**/*.jsx',
    //'<rootDir>/src/**/*.tsx',
  ],
  coveragePathIgnorePatterns: ['/node_modules/', '.d.ts$'],
  coverageThreshold: {
    global: {
      //  branches: 50,
      //  functions: 40,
      //  lines: 50,
      //  statements: 50
    },
  },
  testMatch: [
    // Matches tests in any subfolder of 'src' or into 'test/jest/__tests__'
    // Matches all files with extension 'js', 'jsx', 'ts' and 'tsx'
    '<rootDir>/test/jest/__tests__/**/*.(spec|test).+(ts|js)?(x)',
    '<rootDir>/src/**/*.jest.(spec|test).+(ts|js)?(x)',
  ],
  // Extension-less imports of components are resolved to .ts files by TS,
  //  grating correct type-checking in test files.
  // Being 'vue' the first moduleFileExtension option, the very same imports
  //  will be resolved to .vue files by Jest, if both .vue and .ts files are
  //  in the same folder.
  // This guarantee a great dev experience both for testing and type-checking.
  // See https://github.com/vuejs/vue-jest/issues/188#issuecomment-620750728
  moduleFileExtensions: ['vue', 'js', 'jsx', 'json', 'ts', 'tsx'],
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '^~/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/$1',
    '^src/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/$1',
    '^app/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/$1',
    '^components/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/components/$1',
    '^layouts/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/layouts/$1',
    '^pages/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/pages/$1',
    '^assets/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/assets/$1',
    '^boot/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/boot/$1',
    '.*css$': '@quasar/quasar-app-extension-testing-unit-jest/stub.css',
  },
  transform: {
    // See https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration.html#transformignorepatterns-array-string
    [`^(${esModules}).+\\.js$`]: 'babel-jest',
    '^.+\\.(ts|js|html)$': 'ts-jest',
    // vue-jest uses find-babel-file, which searches by this order:
    //  (async) .babelrc, .babelrc.js, package.json, babel.config.js
    //  (sync) .babelrc, .babelrc.js, babel.config.js, package.json
    // https://github.com/tleunen/find-babel-config/issues/33
    '.*\\.vue$': 'vue-jest',
    '.+\\.(css|styl|less|sass|scss|svg|png|jpg|ttf|woff|woff2)$':
      'jest-transform-stub',
  },
  transformIgnorePatterns: [`<rootDir>/node_modules/(?!(${esModules}))`],
  snapshotSerializers: ['<rootDir>/node_modules/jest-serializer-vue'],
};
```

.babelrc

```
{
  "plugins": ["@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import"],
  "env": {
    "test": {
      "plugins": ["dynamic-import-node"],
      "presets": [
        [
          "@babel/preset-env",
          {
            "modules": "commonjs",
            "targets": {
              "node": "current"
            }
          }
        ]
      ]
    }
  }
}
```